# In R, apply the cut (segmentation) of one vector to the other

Tags: r

Here is an example of the problem I have:

I have a vector v:

```
v <- 1:10
```

I can use `Hmisc::cut2` to evenly split it into 5 groups, for which I first need:

```
library(Hmisc)
cut2(v, g=5)
```

To check:

```
table(cut2(v, g=5))
[1, 3) [3, 5) [5, 7) [7, 9) [9,10] 
2      2      2      2      2
```

Now I have another vector:

```
v2 <- 1:8
```

I want to apply the exact same cut of v to v2 such that for v2 there are also 5 groups whereas the last group [9, 10] has 0 element. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I think to use cut2 you need to install the Hmisc package. It's used to cut a numeric variable into intervals.

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 You should edit your question to mention that `cut2` comes from `Hmisc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use `v2` in order to index from `cut2(v, g = 5)`

```
table(cut2(v, g = 5)[v2])
# [1, 3) [3, 5) [5, 7) [7, 9) [9,10] 
#      2      2      2      2      0
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
table(cut2(v2,cuts=c(1,3,5,7,9,10)))

[ 1, 3) [ 3, 5) [ 5, 7) [ 7, 9) [ 9,10] 
    2       2       2       2       0
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks! This would work. Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to type in c(1,3,5,7,9,10)?

Comment: See David's answer, it requires inputting less code. Does that help solve your problem?